# Tkinter avoid/disable Window movement (or its dragging)

Tags: tkinter, window, root, disable

I have a root.tk() window "zoomed" (maximized) and non resizable and now I would like to avoid that the mouse draggs it because it causes that the root.tk() window minimizes.

I only want the root.tk() window hides with the "desktop hide button" in different operating systems.

I tried with bind events and some stuff I found browsing.

Any ideas please?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far please

Answer (score 0):

Really I've only found this code to do similar what I want to do:

```
import tkinter

def GetWindowPos():
    global X,Y
    X = win.winfo_geometry().split("+")[1]
    Y = win.winfo_geometry().split("+")[2]
    win.bind_all('<Configure>', HoldOn)

def HoldOn(event):
    win.geometry("+{}+{}".format(X,Y))

win = tkinter.Tk()
win.geometry("400x400+{}+{}".format(12,12))
tkinter.Label(win,text="Halo!").grid()
win.after(100,GetWindowPos)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Its always full screen right? So getting the geometry is pointless, because it should always be in the format of `width_of_screen x height_of_screen + 0 + 0`, make a function to this and `bind` it to `<Configure>`. Also what is wrong with this code, seems to work, even though it is the long way

Answer (score 0):

This works, but root is blinking all time once it has been moved:

```
import tkinter

def HoldOn(event):
    w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.state("zoomed")
root.bind_all('<Configure>', HoldOn)

root.mainloop()
```